# Coalition Games

Tags: list-manipulation, algorithm

Suppose an election produces the following result:

```
result = {{"a", 120}, {"b", 80}, {"c", 50}, {"d", 30}};
```

Letters are parties and numbers seats.

To form a majority coalition a minimum of 141 seats is required:

```
n = Total[Last /@ result]/2 + 1
```

> 141

What now follows is my naive attempt to find all possible majority coalitions

```
subs = Most @ Rest @ Subsets[result];
```

(`Most` and `Rest` exclude  the empty set `{}` (negotiations failed) and the trivial case of an all - party - coalition)

One party

```
p1 = subs /. {{a_, b_}} :> {{a, b, b - n}};
```

Two parties

```
p2 = p1 /. {{a_, b_}, {c_, d_}} :> {{a <> c, b + d, b + d - n}};
```

Three parties

```
p3 = p2 /. {{a_, b_}, {c_, d_}, {e_, f_}} :> {{a <> c <> e, b + d + f,b + d + f - n}};
```

Solution

```
Reverse @ SortBy[DeleteCases[Catenate @ p3, {__, a_?Negative}], Last] // TableForm
```

[image]

My attempt would get utterly complicated for, let' s say, 10 parties.

How could an elegant solution for an arbitrary number of parties look like?

Comment: I posted an answer.  It seems "elegant" to me, but I don't know if its what you're getting at.  I would be more concerned with performance than elegance on a problem like this, yet you made no specific mention of that.  Either way I hope it helps.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard +1 Works nicely even with 10 parties. A stylish solution :)

Comment: Are you really interested in coalitions that are larger than they need to be? How common is that in practice in the political structure you're modeling? I feel like my real world knowledge says that if A+B and A+B+C are both valid majority coalitions, then A+B is more likely and they will intentionally exclude C to increase their own relative power.

Comment: @Sparr "coalitions [that are] larger than they need to be" are very common in Europe.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My straightforward solution:

```
TakeWhile[Rest@Reverse@SortBy[{{} <> #, Total@#2} & @@@ 
     Transpose /@ Subsets[result, {1, ∞}], Last], #[[2]] > n &] // Grid
```

[image]

---

Let me do it as fast as possible. I know that you ask an elegant solution but tuning the efficiency is also interesting. One can note that `Total` and `StringJoin` works slow on subsets. So I propose

```
k = 14;
result = Transpose@{FromCharacterCode /@ Range[97, 96 + k], 
   RandomInteger[{1, 100}, k]}
n = Total[Last /@ result]/2 + 1
(* {{"a", 46}, {"b", 16}, {"c", 39}, {"d", 6}, {"e", 44}, {"f",
   14}, {"g", 1}, {"h", 68}, {"i", 90}, {"j", 69}, {"k", 65}, {"l", 
  94}, {"m", 68}, {"n", 10}} *)
(* 316 *)

coalitions = With[{p = UnitStep[# - N@n]},
      Transpose[Append[Transpose[#2], #]][[Reverse@Ordering@#]] &[
       Pick[#, p, 1],
       Pick[Tuples[{" ", "x"}, Length@result], p, 1]]] &@
    Fold[Join[#, +##] &, {0}, 
     Reverse@result[[All, 2]]]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.026954, Null} *)
```

This solutions is more complicated but it is 10 times faster!

Top-10 and Bottom-10 majority coalitions:

```
TableForm[{coalitions[[2 ;; 11]]\[Transpose], 
  coalitions[[-10 ;;]]\[Transpose]}, 
 TableHeadings -> {None, Append[result[[All, 1]], "weight"]}, 
 TableDepth -> 3, TableSpacing -> {2, 2, 0}, 
 TableAlignments -> Center]
```

[image]

P.S. It is amazing that `Fold[Join[#, +##] &, {0}, list]` is 200 times faster than `Total[Subsets[list], {2}]`.

Comment: The all-party coalition should be excluded.

Comment: @RunnyKine, OK.

Comment: Nice, +1 :)....

Comment: I love the use of `Fold` and `+##`! :-)

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps I am overlooking something but this seems like a straightforward subset sum problem, and since you appear to accept the computational and memory complexity of generating a power set it can be implemented simply:

```
Select[
 Subsets[result][[2 ;; -2]] ~Total~ {2},
 #[[2]] >= n &
]
```

> ```
> {{"a" + "b", 200}, {"a" + "c", 170}, {"a" + "d", 150}, {"a" + "b" + "c", 250},
>  {"a" + "b" + "d", 230}, {"a" + "c" + "d", 200}, {"b" + "c" + "d", 160}}
> ```

Formatting included:

```
Cases[
  Subsets[result][[2 ;; -2]] ~Total~ {2},
  {p_, c_} /; c >= n :> {StringJoin @@ p, c, c - n}
] // SortBy[-#[[2]] &] // TableForm
```

$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 \text{abc} & 250 & 109 \\
 \text{abd} & 230 & 89 \\
 \text{acd} & 200 & 59 \\
 \text{ab} & 200 & 59 \\
 \text{ac} & 170 & 29 \\
 \text{bcd} & 160 & 19 \\
 \text{ad} & 150 & 9 \\
\end{array}
\right)$

Answer (score 4):

Here is a variation of Mr.Wizard's answer using `Pick` and making it into a function. Here, `nP` is the number of parties involved.

```
coalitionGames[result_, nP_Integer] := With[{n = Last @ Total[result] / 2 + 1, 
   lis = Subsets[result, {1, nP - 1}] ~Total~ {2},  Pick[lis, UnitStep @ (n - lis[[All, 2]]), 0]]
```

Then:

```
SortBy[coalitionGames[result, 4], -#[[2]] &] /. {x_, y_} :> {StringJoin @@ x, y} // TableForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 4):

```
result = {{"a", 120}, {"b", 80}, {"c", 50}, {"d", 30}};

{players, worths} = Transpose[result];
indices = Subsets[Range@Length@players, {1, Infinity}]; 
majoritycoalitions = Pick[indices, Total[worths[[#]]] >= 141 & /@ indices];

table = SortBy[{Row@players[[#]], Total[worths[[#]]], Total[worths[[#]]] - 141} & /@
    majoritycoalitions, -Last[#] &];
Grid[Join[{{"coalitions", "total weight", "excess"}}, table], Dividers -> All]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is certainly not as elegant as others and also I have used subsets twice which seems redundant.

```
partyResult[list_] := Module[{},

allParties = DeleteCases[Subsets[Cases[list, {a_, b_} -> a]], {}];
allvotes = DeleteCases[Subsets[Cases[list, {a_, b_} -> b]], {}];

allparSum = Cases[Total[allvotes, {2}], _?(# >= 141 &)];
allsumpos = 
Extract[allParties, Position[Total[allvotes, {2}], _?(# >= 141 &)]];

Grid[{allsumpos[[#]], allparSum[[#]]} & /@ Range[Length[allparSum]],
Frame -> All]
]

result = {{"a", 120}, {"b", 80}, {"c", 50}, {"d", 30}};     
partyResult[result]
```

[image]